# Linking containers across networks

Tags: linux, docker, networking, rancher

I have two containers a webapp and a database.

The webapp is is on network 10.10.1.10/24 using macvlan driver for this user defined network and the name of this network is **mnet**

link/ether 02:42:0a:84:01:05 
    inet 10.10.1.10/24 scope global eth0

Db container is on inet 10.10.11.2/24 scope global eth0

Using bridge driver for this user defined network and the name of this network is **int**

I can ping the gateway of mnet ( 10.10.10.1 ) and all other machines on local network but not the webapp (10.10.10.5 ) hosted in docker from db container.

I want to link the webapp with db on this network but not been able to establish a connection with db or vice versa.

I can link both if i put the db container on same as webapp network.

Reason i don't want them to put on the same network is that **mnet** is integrated with our LAN so i want to isolate users from accessing the db container.

Environment : Production

Docker version:   17.03.1-ce

OS :  RancherOs

Is there any work around,reason or solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A container can be on multiple networks. Make a new user defined network and put both the DB and web app on that. Then when they want to talk to each other they will use this new network but other traffic will use your existing networks.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
You are right but if i put both of them on internal network (bridge) then i have to expose ports for the web app and have to use docker host IP which is not ideal. 
Thats why i was looking for a way to put db on internal and wepapp on "macvlan" network which is integrated with my local lan

Comment: Imagine a scenario where you have three networks. Macvlan, internal/bridge and a third new one webapp-db just for the connection between the two.